# Windows error with composer create new symfony project

Tags: composer-php

I install composer on Windows and when I try to create new symfony project i obtain the following error:
[errorException]
mkdir(): no souch file or directory.

Why i have this error?

Comment: Could you provide more details?

Comment: If i create the project from another directory it works. Windows composer isnt globally?

Comment: Sounds like configuration issue